Как избавиться от None в выдаче результата функции print()?
Прошу не судить строго -- я только учусь.
Задача: нужно написать класс генератора простых чисел.
Ограничение: необходимо вызывать объект генератора при помощи функции print(next()). Автотесты проверяют код при помощи print(next()) и ожидают на выходе список простых чисел от 2 до 11: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11].
Проблема: написанный мной код, помимо простых чисел, выдаёт ещё и None для всех составных чисел, что не соответствует ожидаемой выдаче.
Вопрос: как перехватить/избавиться от None в выдаче при использовании print()?
PS: нашёл похожую проблему здесь, но предложенные решения не подошли, либо я не нашёл, как их адаптировать.
Спасибо!
class PrimeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, stop):
        self.stop = stop
        self.i = 2

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            if self.i < self.stop:
                current = self.i
                self.i += 1
                for number in range(2, current):
                    if current % number == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    return current
        except:
            StopIteration()


g = PrimeGenerator(12)

print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))


Если вы попадаете в if current % number == 0: вы ничего не возвращаете вот вам и первые None, далее если не сработает if self.i < self.stop: вы так же ничего не возвращаете, это ваши None после 12. Возможно, вам надо собрать все числа в список и его возвращать?

Необходимо переписать метод next так, что бы он обходил последовательность чисел, и накапливал найденные простые числа и их возвращал списком
class PrimeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, stop):
        self.stop = stop
        self.begin = 2

    def __next__(self):
        # Создаем список
        simple = []
        current = self.begin
        try:
            # Пока не достигли предела
            while current <= self.stop:
                # Проверяем на простоту
                for number in range(2, current):
                    if current % number == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    # Если число простое, добавляем в список
                    simple.append(current)
                # Увеличиваем счетчик
                current += 1
            # Возвращаем полученный список простых чисел
            return simple
        except:
            StopIteration()


print(next(PrimeGenerator(12)))
print(next(PrimeGenerator(32)))
print(next(PrimeGenerator(64)))
print(next(PrimeGenerator(128)))


Я так понимаю, идея была такая, что каждый вызов next должен выдавать следующее число, а не полный список.

@insolor одной функцией весь итератор не проверить. Судя из описания вопроса от 2 до 11: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]. ответ верный. Да и итератор должен когда то закончится, судя по задаче, а если для 12 вызвать его 50 раз - тут уже None не избежать или как то в цикл это заворачивать или перед print проверять, что вернулось правильное число(если вышли за лимит возвращать 0 к примеру)

"Судя из описания вопроса от 2 до 11: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]. ответ верный." - я подозреваю, что условие криво описано. Если так, то это очень странный итератор. Я бы скорее ориентировался на здравый смысл, а не на буквальное описание. Про None - да, нужно в цикл заворачивать.

@insolor Ну если описание кривое и к нему не подходит этот ответ, то я его удалю, делов то... Дождемся мнения автора вопроса
